# Access game objects by coordinates while still being able to move them easily

Tags: java, arrays, collections, coordinates

I'm currently working on a game written in Java.
At the moment I'm stuck finding an easy way to store my GameObjects (Player, Enemies, and so on...) so that I can access them by their coordinates while still being able to move them easily.

I already tried Multidimensional Arrays, which is nice, but won't let me move my Objects easily. I'd have to physically move the Object in the array every time it moves.

Then I tried "normal" Arrays, which lets you move things easily, just increase the objects x, y or z value, but won't allow me to access Objects by coordinates without iterating through the whole array.

Right now, i'm trying to find a compromise that allows me to have both.

Thanks in advance,
//265

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to use **both** forms at the same time. Store the coordinates in your `GameObject` instances, but also simultaneously cache them in your 3D array. The array should preferably be encapsulated in an object that provides method to update and query it. Something like this:

```
public class GameObjectDatabase implements LocationChangeListener {

    private int [] [] [] data;

    private Set<GameObjects> objects;

    ...

    public GameObject gameObjectAt(int x, int y, int z) {
        return data[x][y][z];
    }

    @Override
    public void positionUpdated(GameObject obj, int oldX, int oldY, int oldZ) {
      ....
    }

}
```

Why the listener and the overridden method? Because it's not really your `GameObject`'s job to update this data - it's the responsibility of the `GameObjectDatabase`. So, ideally, your `GameObject` should allow to register listeners in a `Set` and call their `positionUpdated` methods every time its location changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think that's how I'll do it. :)

Comment: I'll probably make the GameObject concrete implementation not just interfaces, let them have getters and setters for position to easily catch position changes for the GameObjectDatabase

Comment: @Ferdi265 : that's definitely OK in this case. Just don't depend on inheritance for code reuse too much when writing your game. If you want more info, [there's an excellent blog article about this](http://replicaisland.blogspot.com/2009/09/aggregate-objects-via-components.html).

Answer (score 0):

All game objects that have a position (player, enemies etc) should have an internal reference to their position eg;

```
class Position {
  int x;
  int y;
}

interface Positionable {
  Position getPosition();
  void setPosition(int x, int y, GameArea area);
}

class Player implements Positionable {
  //stuff
}

class Enemy implements Positionable {
  //stuff
}
```

You can then have a class representing your game area;

```
class GameArea {

  Positionable[][] grid;
  List<Positionable> gameObjects;

  public Positionable getByLocation(int x, int y) {
    return grid[x][y];
  }

  public void setAtLocation(int x, int y, Positionable p) {
    grid[x][y] = p;
  }

  public List<Positionable> getAll() {
    return gameObjects;
  }

}
```

This allows you to access by position and iterate over all objects. When a game object moves it needs to update its position internally and explicitly update the `GameArea`, as shown in the below example `setPosition()` implementation.

```
void setPosition(int x, int y, GameArea area) {
  area.setAtLocation(this.x, this.y, null);
  area.setAtLocation(x, y, this);
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
```